# $L_p$ norm of $l_q$ norm of gaussian vector

Tags: probability

Let $G_n = (g_1,\ldots,g_n)$, where $g_i$ are independent, standard Gaussian variables. I want to estimate (find lower and upper bound) of $(\mathbb{E}\|G_n\|_q^p)^\frac{1}{p}$.

So, equivalently, we can try to estimate $\mathbb{P}(\sum |g_i|^q >t^q)$. I've tried to find the distribution of sum of half normal variables raised to some power, but it gets me nowhere.

Of course, I can try to estimate like $\mathbb{P}(\sum |g_i|^q >t^q) \le \sum \mathbb{P}(|g_i|^q >t^q)$, but then I lose $q$ parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One often quite effective bound is the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound), especially when there is independence in play.
Applying this here, we get
$$
\mathbb P\left( \sum |g_i|^q > t^q \right)
\le
\mathbb E \left( \exp\bigl(\theta \sum |g_i|^q\bigr) \right) e^{-\theta t^q}
=
e^{-\theta t^q}\prod \mathbb E\bigl(e^{\theta |g_i|^q}\bigr).
$$
This holds for all $\theta \ge 0$. Now do some maths to determine this exponential moment, and then minimise over $\theta$ (or at least choose some $\theta$).

By taking $\theta < 0$, you can consider $\mathbb P(\sum|g_i|^q \le t^q)$.